# How to pass data hexvalue of RGB colour from one computer to another computer

Tags: jquery

Initially i have found RGB value of specific colour e.g #ffff00 now i need to pass this value from my computer to another computer

```
 $(document).on("click", "#Rinc", function () {

            debugger;

            $("[id^='text']").each(function () {

                debugger;

                if ($(this).css('border-style') == 'solid') {

                    currentTb = $(this);

                    var element = $(this);

                    var rgb = element.css('background-color').replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '').replace(/\s/g, '').split(',');

                    //var per = rgb[0] / 255 * 100;

                    if (parseInt(rgb[0]) < 255) {

                        R = Math.round(parseInt(rgb[0]) + 2.55);

                        Rper = R / 255 * 100

                        element.css('background-color', 'rgb(' + R + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')');

                    }

                }
            });
            $('#Rtxtbox').val(Math.round(Rper));
        });
```

Similarly I have found colour of R,G,B values in Jquery and transmit these values to another computer in bit transmission or is there any other way

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'transmit to another computer' ? do you want to post these values to a backend?